# How to parse below JSON with the help of volley to GET request in android please give some code?

Tags: android, android-volley

{
  "num_results": 1, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "birth_date": null, 
      "computers": [], 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Read a book"
    }
  ], 
  "page": 1, 
  "total_pages": 1
}

Comment: Volley isn't used for parsing JSON.  Its used for downloading http urls.  To parse JSON, you'd use either JSONObject or a 3rd party library like GSON or Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  native code

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
jsonObject.getString("num_results");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("objects");
    //create a model class (Name MyModel) with 3 field name birth_date,id, name
      MyModel myModel = null;
      //create a vector to hold data
  Vector<MyModel> dataHolderVector = new Vector<MyModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        myModel = new MyModel();
        final JSONObject catchObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        try{
            dto.setBirthDate(catchObject, "birth_date"));
            dto.setId(catchObject, "id"));
            dto.setName(Utility.getJsonText(catchObject, "name"));
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        dataHolderVector.addElement(myModel);
        myModel = null;

    }
```

*** you dont provide computers[]  element

Comment: how will you access the elements of the jsonArray

Comment: JSONArray a = response.getJSONArray("objects");
                     for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) a.get(i);
                        String name = person.getString("name");  problem solved